# Is Internet Explorer 11 supported on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-server-2019

I know IE 11 is supposed to be supported until 2025. Has anyone confirmed if it's possible to run IE 11 (including legacy web apps with ActiveX) in Windows 2019?

Or do you need stick to the older Server OSs if you have to keep using IE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Internet Explorer 11 is available on Windows Server 2019.

According to the [Internet Explorer Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer), it is still supported.

[This Microsoft article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-work/whats-new-wip-at-work-1809) states that app compatibility for IE11 is an optional "Feature on Demand". I'm assuming that you have to enable it.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55446042/109941) how to install it.

Comment: The "feature on demand" thing is only related to Server Core installation; if you install the full-GUI Windows Server 2019, IE11 is just right there.

Comment: @Massimo thank you for the clarification. I haven’t had a chance to try out Server 2019 yet.